# How to draw a string array into a Java Applet?

Tags: java, arrays, string, graphics, applet

I'm amateur when it comes to java, I am trying to create an applet that randomizes the sequence "Black Screen British Guy" into a different sequence. e.x. "Screen Black Guy British"

I have got the sequence to print to console, However I am trying to print the strings into a java applet, I'm having trouble with this, and I could use some help. Thanks.

```
 package bsbg_gen;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class main extends Applet {

        public void init(){
             String[] bsbg;
             String[] bsbg2;
             String[] bsbg3;
             String[] bsbg4;

             String [][] name = {{"Black"}, {"Screen"}, {"British"}, {"Guy"}};
             String [][] name2 = {{"Black"}, {"Screen"}, {"British"}, {"Guy"}};
             String [][] name3 = {{"Black"}, {"Screen"}, {"British"}, {"Guy"}};
             String [][] name4 = {{"Black"}, {"Screen"}, {"British"}, {"Guy"}};

             Random rand = new Random();

             bsbg = name [rand.nextInt(name.length)];
             bsbg2 = name2 [rand.nextInt(name2.length)];
             bsbg3 = name3 [rand.nextInt(name3.length)];
             bsbg4 = name4 [rand.nextInt(name4.length)];


             System.out.print(Arrays.toString(bsbg));
             System.out.print(Arrays.toString(bsbg2));
             System.out.print(Arrays.toString(bsbg3));
             System.out.print(Arrays.toString(bsbg4));
        }

        public void stop(){
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){

            g.drawString((Arrays.toString(bsbg)), 150, 50);

            g.drawString((Arrays.toString(bsbg2)), 150, 50);

            g.drawString((Arrays.toString(bsbg3)), 175, 50);

            g.drawString((Arrays.toString(bsbg4)), 200, 50);
        }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: _" I'm having trouble with this"_ - You never explained what the trouble is, or even asked a question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's in applet form so it can be embedded into a website.

Comment: *"It's in applet form so it can be embedded into a website."*  Use JavaScript.  It will work a lot better for things like this.

Comment: @peeskillet yes i did.. I asked how I could use something similar to this, however use a java applet and have the strings printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare these as class members. They're currently not within the scope of the `paint` method. They're localized in the `init` method. Take them out.

```
String[] bsbg;
String[] bsbg2;
String[] bsbg3;
String[] bsbg4;
```

Declare them outside

```
String[] bsbg;
String[] bsbg2;
String[] bsbg3;
String[] bsbg4;

public void init(){
```